# what's the use of .count command in repeat while loop?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I recently began to study swift as my first programming language and there's a very simple term that i can't find an answer for it.

take a look at this code:

```
var a = [Int]()
repeat {
    
    let randomNumbers = Int.random(in: 0...10)
    if a.contains(randomNumbers) == false {
        
        a.append(randomNumbers)
        
    }
    
    print(randomNumbers)
    
} while (a.count < 10)
```

so this code is supposed to add 10 numbers (no duplicates) from 0...10 into the array until all unique integers are listed. what I don't understand is the role of "while" here.
doesn't the last line mean the number of "generated numbers" must be less than 10? then why every time I run the code I get more than 10 numbers (say 30-40) in the console?
Also according to the code, this code must not generate dupes. then why do I get some numbers printed 2,3 times in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you check if `randomNumbers` already added to array `a`, if yes, the loop will be executed again, until `a.count < 10`.

if you move the `print` statement inside the `if` statement, it will be printed exactly 10 times.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. when I move the **print** statement inside the **if** statement it will be printed exactly 10 times but here's the problem : Not every integers are listed. in other words a number is always missing. according to the code it must list all integers from 0..10

Comment: `0...10` means 0 and 10 are included, which gives you 11 number in total, so you need to modify the while condition to `a.count < 11`

Comment: Oh man you are a life saver. I couldn't understand it till u explained. thank u sm!

Comment: @OsamaBinLaden note that you are always printing the randomNumbers regardless if the random number was a duplicate number or not. So it might print more than 10 times if you use a larger range of integers. Btw it would be much easier to just shuffle the 0...10 range and drop the last number `let randomNumbers = (0...10).shuffled().dropLast()`

Comment: GOT IT!  tnx@LeoDabus